# Given 2 3D objects, how do I calculate the rotation Yaw & Pitch to face the object?

Tags: java, math, rotation

I have never been good with 3D match. Here is a picture
[image]

This is just a MS Paint mockup.

Figure 1 is just the current state, Figure 2 is what I am trying to accomplish. I would like the Red Object to be facing the Green Object.

Comment: @Ugleh look up "quarternions" - for a given initial transformation and a target transformation I believe they give the best option for a "natural" looking transition from one to the other.   I don't have the math to explain them myself, though.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation

Answer (score 0):

Yaw and pitch can be applied in several orders. Here, I assume that yaw (rotation about the depth axis in the image) is applied first. Modify the following formulas based on your coordinate system and specification.

Yaw can be calculated from the coordinate differences on the two remaining axes (x and y in this case):

```
yaw = atan2(target.x - source.x, target.y - source.y)
```

You may need to swap source and target and/or x and y based on your coordinate system.

Then, pitch is:

```
pitch = atan(target.z - source.z, sqrt((target.x - source.x)² + (target.y - source.y)²)
```